# In an unordered array, isnt the time complexity of removing an element O(n)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I read somewhere that it is O(1). However, if we need to remove an element from an array we need to swap all the elements to the left and in the worst case wont  will it need to make N swaps which makes the complexity O(n)? I am confused?! Also is there a difference between an unordered and an unsorted array??

Comment: The O(n) you specified is needed to maintain your array (which is optional) but not for removing the element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array is unordered, you can fill the hole with the last element, and then shorten the array by 1. No need to shift every element down one position.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how you want to remove the element-i.e., by supplying index or value of element-it is `O(1)` or `O(n)`.